# Search string and add string at end of line but before quotes using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am seeking help to find string and add string in end of line but before quotes

file output:

```
 I have a file
 search_string="It has some text"
 some other text
```

I tried below method:

```
 sed -i '/^search_string=/ s/$/ add_string one add_string two/' file
```

I am getting below output:

```
 I have a file
 search_string="It has some text" add_string one add_string two
 some other text
```

expected output:

```
 I have a file
 search_string="It has some text add_string one add_string two"
 some other text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/search_string="[^"]*/& add_string_one add string two/' file
```

You can do it in-place, with `-i`:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/search_string="[^"]*/& add_string_one add string two/' file

$ diff file.bak file
2c2
< search_string="It has some text"
---
> search_string="It has some text add_string_one add string two"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^.*search_string=/ s/\(.*\)"/\1 add_string one add_string two"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

simple modification to OP's code

```
$ sed '/^search_string=/ s/"$/ add_string one add_string two"/' file
I have a file
search_string="It has some text add_string one add_string two"
some other text
```

- `"$` match double quotes at end of line
- in replacement section, add the quote as well

Or to avoid repeating text for longer text, use `&`. For example:

```
$ sed '/^search_string=/ s/ text"$/ add_string one add_string two&/' file
I have a file
search_string="It has some add_string one add_string two text"
some other text
```